# Continuous integration solution

Tags: webdriver, protractor, continuous-integration, jira, testlink

I need to automate a whole solution from test case specifications to deployment.

This is the plan I am thinking about:

- Using a planning tool such as JIRA to manage all my test cases.
- Developers working on Angular JS
- GitHub as a Version Control System
- Jenkins as Continuous Integration tool which will manage the builds
- Webdriver/Protractor to automate the test cases and another tool for unit tests

My questions:

1. Do you think JIRA is suitable to manage my test cases? Can I use Testlink instead? What would be the limitations with Testlink?
2. Related to my plan, do you have any feedback or recommendations? Easy to set up?
3. Do you have another idea to manage this whole process? The only thing to keep from my plan would be the testing scripts. How can I automate everything around these testing scripts?

Any inputs will be highly appreciated.
Have a good day all :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Why you need to manage your test cases at all? Who will manage your test cases? Are you sure you really need "manage" them?
2. Plan is good, I want just add that tests should run on each push to GitHub, and if tests fail then merge is blocked.
3. What exactly scripts do you mean? As for me, if you use Jenkins, make your deploy in daclarative way - use `Jenkinsfile`.

Comment: Hi Oleksii, sorry for my late reply. Yes I want to manage all my test cases in one place. Ok thank you for your tip about the merge. I am not familiar with that yet. My scripts will be written with webdriver or protractor.